# Why am I not able to hide an HTML div (containing a datatable) before rendering it again in my Rails app?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, datatables

**Background**

This is a crisp explanation of what I am trying to do:

1. I have a Rails form (am calling it a 'pre-search' form) which contains a dropdown
2. When the dropdown selection is changed, a search form is displayed to the user (the form allows the user to select some search criteria)
   This form contains a "Run Search" button which is used to submit the form selections
3. When "Run Search" is clicked on the above form, a datatable is displayed right below the form

**The Issue**

And this is my issue:

4. When the search criteria in the above form is changed and "Run Search" is clicked again, I would like:
   I.  The datatable that was displayed earlier to be removed and 
   II. A new datatable to be displayed in the place where the old datatable was displayed.

But this does not happen. I see that additional datatables get added to the page instead of deleting the old one and replacing it everytime. So if I run search 4 times, I see 4 datatables in the page. I would like to see only 1 datatable how many ever times I run the search.

**Code**

This is my pre-search form with a dropdown:

```rb
<%= form_for :anything, remote: true, html: { id: 'pre_search_form' } do |f| %>
  <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px">

      <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label style="font-weight: 600;font-size:95%"><b>Category : </b>&nbsp;<%= select_tag(:search_category, options_for_select([['-Select-', ''], ['Option1', 'o1'], ['Option 2', 'o2'], ['Option 3', 'o3'], ['Option 4', 'o4']], :selected => 0)) %></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of row 1 -->

  </div>

  <div id="dummy_div"> </div>

  <div id="datatable_div"></div>

<% end %>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(function() {
   $(document).on("change", "#search_category", function(event){

     $.ajax('show_search_form', {
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'script',
       data: {
         search_category: $("#search_category").val()
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
       }
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

This is the routes entry that gets called when the dropdown selection is changed in the above 'pre-search' form:

**routes.rb**

```rb
get "/show_search_form" => "search#show_search_form", :as => :show_search_form
```

This is the controller function that is executed due to the routes entry above:

**search_controller.rb**

```rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def show_search_form
    render :partial => "search/show_search_form.js.erb"
  end
```

This is the partial rendered by above controller function:

**search/show_search_form.js.erb**

```rb
<%= form_for :anything, remote: true, html: { id: 'search_form' } do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
      <b><%= label_tag "Entity" %><br/></b>
      <%= select_tag(:search_entity, options_for_select([["Entity 1", 1], ["Entity 2", 2]]) %>
  </div>

  <%= button_tag 'Run Search', type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', id: "search_run_button" %> 
<%end%>


<!-- Javascript code to handle events for dropdowns in the above form-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
  /* Handle event when "Run Search" button is clicked */
   $(document).on("click", "#search_run_button", function(event){
    $.ajax('search_run', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        search_entity: $("#search_entity").val()
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the routes entry for the button click in above form:

```rb
get "/search_run" => "search#run_search", :as => :search_run
```

This is the controller function called by the routes entry above:

```rb
  def run_search
    logger.info "SearchController run_search"

    $search_entity = params[:search_entity]

    data_table = SearchDatatable.new(view_context)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: {
          "pageLength"      => data_table.page_length,
          "recordsTotal"    => data_table.records_total,
          "recordsFiltered" => data_table.records_filtered,
          "data"            => data_table.run_data
        }
      end
    end    
    render :partial => "search/run_search.js.erb"
  end
```

This is the partial called by the controller function above:

**search/run_search.js.erb**

```rb
$('#datatable_div').hide();
$('#datatable_div').hide().after('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search/run_search')) %>');
```

As you can see, I am hiding `datatable_div` before rendering the datatable. But still, datatables get appended to the page instead of being overwritten.

How can I overwrite the `datatable_div` everytime so that irrespective of the number of searches done on the page, ONLY ONE datatable gets shown ALWAYS?

Please help!

This is the datatable rendering code just in case this is relevant:

**search/run_search.html.erb**

```rb
<div id="datatable_div">
  <%= content_tag :table, 
                  role: :search_datatable, 
                  id: 'search_datatable', 
                  style: 'height:500px; width: 100vw; overflow-y: auto;',
                  class: 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 
                  data: { url: search_datatable_path(format: :json)} do %>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>

  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("table[role='search_datatable']").each(function(){
      var table = $(this).DataTable({
        columnDefs: [ 
        { "orderable": true, "targets": 1}, 
        ],
        aoColumns: [
              { mData: 'column1' },
              { mData: 'column2' }
          ],      
        autoWidth: true,
        pageLength: 50,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        sDom: 'ltipr',
        ajax: $(this).data('url')
      });
    });
  });  
</script>
```

I tried these based on the comments from fellow stackoverflow users:

**Approach 1** (based on @MikeHeft suggestion)

**Approach 1. a)**

```rb
$('#datatable_div').html('').html('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search/dbr/run_search')) %>');
```

**What happened with this approach?**

This would not render the datatable even the very first time. It won't render any datatable - ever.

**Approach 1. b)**

```rb
$('#datatable_div').html('').after('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search/dbr/run_search')) %>');
```

**What happened after this approach?**

This would render the datatable all right - but it still takes me back to my original issue - it won't replace the existing datatable the next time I run search. It just keeps adding more and more datatables to my search page.

Comment: You could possibly try to set the html to an empty string and then set the hmtl to the new datatable.  `$('#datetable').html('').html("<%= j render 'path/to/partial'%>")`

Comment: Can you reload the table data with a new ajax url? `tableObject.ajax.url('new-url').load();`

Comment: @MikeHeft - I tried your suggestion; it didn't give desired results. I have updated my question with what I tried based on your suggestion and what were the outcomes.

Comment: @Mark - I tried this `$('#search_datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();` in `_run_search.js.erb` but it won't render the datatable the first time. Is there a way to check if the `search_datatable` has already been rendered (if yes, then call `$('#search_datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();` if not then call `$('#datatable_div').hide().after('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search/run_search')) %>');`?  Am guessing this approach should work? Am not sure how to check if `search_datatable` already has been rendered or not. Pls help!

Comment: You could set the datatables option `destroy: true` or the `tableObject.destroy()` method, which will remove a datatable if it exists before creating a new one, but that seems like the nuclear option to me. Maybe create your datatable separately with `ajax: ''` then use the `ajax.url()` method within your search function. You could hide the div containing the datatable when there is no data to display.